# How can I write a python code that searches for a word in a string and then prints the string if word is present

Tags: list, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension, any

Here is a scenario:

Given:

```
facility_list = ['port', 'airport']

location_list =[ 'new york', 'Manchester', 'lagos port','florida port', 'london','Durban airport' ]
```

Task:

For each location in `location_list`,

If its name  has 'port' or 'airport' in it,

print:
{name} is cool! .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
facility_list = ["port", "airport"]
location_list = [
    "new york",
    "Manchester",
    "lagos port",
    "florida port",
    "london",
    "Durban airport",
]

for name in location_list:
    if any(facility in name for facility in facility_list):
        print(f"{name} is cool!")
```

Prints:

```
lagos port is cool!
florida port is cool!
Durban airport is cool!
```

---

OR: If you want to check separate words in location name, you can use `str.split()`:

```py
for name in location_list:
    if any(facility in name.split() for facility in facility_list):
        print(f"{name} is cool!")
```